# Mouse stutters on start up, but works normal after a few minutes

Tags: mouse, windows-10

I've recently got a new computer, and I've noticed when I turn it out, the mouse stutters at first. For the first few minutes, I can move the mouse for a second, then it freezes for a few seconds, then it moves for a second again, etc...

I've currently not got another mouse to try with, but I wondered if any body had any suggestions I could try whilst I try and source another mouse to test with.

I'm running the following

1. Win 10 Pro
2. i7-4790K (Not overclocked)
3. 16gb ram (this was salvaged from my old computer, so it's a few years old)
4. Nvidia 980 ti
5. Mouse is a Razor Oubourous.

If you need any more info, or specs, let me know and I'll add them.

Comment: Only at startup suggests too much stuff happening at startup or a FW/ AV product getting started...

Comment: I only have 8 start up items, and there all low impact apart from 1 medium, but I have a fair few services running. I'll see if any of those aren't needed

Comment: It might not be a needed question, but just what has some issue

Comment: On my Windows 8 machine, the antivirus is still completing a boot-time scan for a minute or so after Windows has started. You might compare startup from a restart (or full shutdown), hybrid shutdown and sleep; often, only the full restart is slow.

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem with my Razer Ouroboros but on win 7. Other Forums suggest removing Razer Synapse 2.xx and switch to an older software or ditch it completely. without synapse the problem is gone. For me, updating to synapse 2.21 helped alot with the stutters since i need the button remapping in my games.